# duplicate records using mapply and then convert the output to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

```
sj <- c("001",'002','003')
st <- c('2017-08-03','2017-08-18','2017-08-30')
diff <- c(350,321,130)

pat <-data.frame(sj,as.Date(st),diff)
```

I want to duplicate each patient by adding st by 1 each time until diff times, that means for sj 001, there will be 351 records, as 2017-08-03, '2017-08-03'+1, '2017-08-03' +2, ..., '2017-08-03' +350. For other patients, so on so forth.

In the end, i need to save the output in a data.frame (not a list).

I tried use mapply as below, but the output is a list, i don't know have to convert it to dataframe

```
expend <- function(USUBJID,st,diff) {
  i <- 0
  if(diff>=0) {
  for (i in seq(0,diff)) {
    dt <- data.frame(sj=USUBJID,sepdate=as.Date((st+i),origin = "1970-01-01"))
    if (i==0) pol <- dt
    else pol <- rbind(pol, dt)

  }
  }
  else {pol <- data.frame(sj=USUBJID,sepdate=st)}
  return(pol)
}

ck<- mapply(FUN=expend,pat$USUBJID,pat$st,pat$diff)
```

I tried use below code to convert the list, ck, to a dataframe, but encounter error.

```
ck1 <- cbind.data.frame(ck[rep(seq_along(ck), lengths(ck)),],
                 res = unlist(ck))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using base R:

```
#split on sj
#and then recreate the data.frame with an lapply function
mylist <- lapply(split(pat, sj), function(x) {
  data.frame(sj = x$sj, Date = x$as.Date.st. + 0:x$diff)
})

#bind the list together in a data.frame
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

Which returns:

```
         sj       Date
001.1   001 2017-08-03
001.2   001 2017-08-04
001.3   001 2017-08-05
001.4   001 2017-08-06
001.5   001 2017-08-07
001.6   001 2017-08-08
001.7   001 2017-08-09
001.8   001 2017-08-10
001.9   001 2017-08-11
001.10  001 2017-08-12
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, we can first create a function which expands the data for `diff + 1` times for each row

```
expand_data <- function(sj, st, diff) {
   data.frame(sj = sj,st = seq(st, length.out = diff + 1, by = "1 day"))
}
```

and then call it using `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(expand_data, pat$sj, pat$st, pat$diff))

#     sj         st
#1   001 2017-08-03 
#2   001 2017-08-04 
#3   001 2017-08-05 
#4   001 2017-08-06 
#5   001 2017-08-07 
#6   001 2017-08-08 
#7   001 2017-08-09 
#....
```

---

We can also use `tidyr::complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pat %>%
  group_by(sj) %>%
  complete(st = seq(st, length.out = diff + 1, by = "1 day")) %>%
  select(-diff)
```

**data**

```
sj <- c("001",'002','003')
st <- as.Date(c('2017-08-03','2017-08-18','2017-08-30'))
diff <- c(350,321,130)
pat <-data.frame(sj,st,diff)
```